# Binomial Distribution test or Comparing Proportions test?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I've been posed the following question:
[image]

Initially, I tried approaching this question by applying a 'comparing proportions' test on the information given. However, there is insufficient information; I cannot calculate the test statistic because the successes and sample size for global influenza is not given. Should I approach this question with null hypothesis: $H_0 = \mathrm{mean}(\text{oceania}) = \mathrm{mean}(\text{global})$ ?

Comment: The population of Oceania is around $40$ million (depending on definition) compared with a world population of around $7,600$ million so I would suggest you test $H_0: \text{ Type A proportion in Oceania } = 0.842$ and $H_1: \text{ Type A proportion in Oceania } \not= 0.842$

Comment: note that the global proportion $0.842$ is the population parameter, not a sample statistic, therefore you must test one-sample (not two-sample) hypothesis test. It would be two-sample, if two samples were selected from two populations (regions). So, the correct hypotheses: $H_0: p=0.842, H_a:p\ne 0.842$.

Comment: Thanks both for your help! much appreciated :)

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29995/how-many-regular-mse-users-frequent-the-meta-page